# How to merge duplicate rows when with same ID with different data

Tags: merge, duplicates, openrefine

I have a data table that looks like this:

| ID | Participação |  | Pessoa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Comunicante |  | Lucas |
| 01 | Vitima |  | Lucas |
| 02 | Comunicante |  | Rafa |
| 02 | Vitima |  | Vitor |

I want to look like this:

| ID | Comunicante |  | Vítima |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Lucas |  | Lucas |
| 02 | Rafa |  | Vitor |

Sometimes Comunicante is different from Vítima because of this I don't want to merge `comunicante,vitima`. I want them in separate columns.

This was so far I made:

| ID | Comunicante |  | Vítima |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Lucas |  |  |
| 01 |  |  | Lucas |
| 02 | Rafa |  |  |
| 02 |  |  | Vitor |

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is called [Tranposing](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/transposing) in OpenRefine.

Starting from your first table go to the column menu on "Participação" => "Transpose" => "Columnize by key/value columns…". In the following dialog use "Participação" as "Key Column" and "Pessoa" as "Value Column".

[image: Columnize by Key/Value Columns dialog in OpenRefine]

The result should look like your desired table.